# Forward subdomain to a new URL but retain the URL entered by the user - Bigrock

Tags: cpanel, cname, domain-forwarding

I have my static website hosted on bigrock.com.. (xyz.com). I recently created a webapp which I am hosting on Amazon AWS. I wanted my subdomain sub.xyz.com to be redirected to the app deployed on AWS.

I created a subdomain in bigrock and redirected the same to the URL of the EC2 instance in AWS. When I did that when I access sub.xyz.com the URL in the browser changes and I get redirected to the amazon app.

How do I hide the EC2 URL and have the user operate out of sub.xyz.com. Also, when I do this, any other URLs like sub.xyz.com/something or sub.xyz.com?something=somethingelse should also work.

Could you please tell me what I need to do on the CPanel of bigrock to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did Amazon AWS provide you with the IP address for your server where you have hosted your application? If yes, you can try adding an A record for the sub-domain and point it to that IP address.

Comment: I just did that.. Didn't know where to do that until now. Then saw the simple DNS Zone editor link on the cpanel. Thanks!